# Brace enclosed initializer lists

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to pass in an array of `Data*` pointers to a function.

```
void f(int argc, Data** argv) {
    ...
}
// at this point, I have Data* x, Data* y initialized
f(2, {x, y});
```

Is there some way to get code like this to run, where the array definition is inline inside the function call? Right now, the error this returns is

```
closure3.cc:15:8: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
closure3.cc:15:16: error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Data**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void f(int, Data**)’
```

Is there some way to get the array instantiated inline, and is it possible to do this without C++0x? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried listening to the warning there and adding `-std=c++0x` to your compiling line?

Comment: Strongly recommend to use vector<vector<Data> > & instead of Data** or change the tag to "C" if you can't use C++.

Comment: ^ That's cute, but do you know of a way to do it inline? And @Cornstalks, I have tried.

Comment: That's C99 almost; `f(2, (Data **){x, y});` is a compound literal.  It isn't part of C++2011 AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider using variable length arguments so you don't have to instantiate the list inline.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I ended up using C++0x and got things working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The brace initializers are only available when declaring an array variable. So you can't do it this way.

Technically you could do it with a function (note: this is untested)

```
Data ** pair_of_data(Data * x, Data * y)
{
  Data ** result = new Data*[2];
  result[0] = x;
  result[1] = y;
  return result;
}
```

but that's ugly for a few reasons:

1. The array ends up on the heap, which is really unnecessary
2. You're asking for a (slight) memory leak every time you use the function.
3. It would need to be overloaded to simulation varargs, or be changed to use varargs and thus lose type safety.

If you specifically need to pass pairs, then consider using `std::pair` instead. These can be created inline using `std::make_pair`.

In the end, though, it's probably easier just to use an STL container, or declare an array variable just before calling the function, so that you use aggregate initialization. Or add the `-std=c++0x` flag.

Answer (score -2):

If you really want it without C++11 features, you may try to do it so (not good sort of code, just to show the idea):

```
vector<int> InitList(int first, ...)
{
    vector<int> arr;
    int *p = &first;

    while(*(p + 1))
    {
        arr.push_back(*p);
        p++;
    }

    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    F(2, InitList(1, 2, 3));
}
```